# Remove part of name ending in dataframe column named .id

Tags: r, dplyr

**Background**

I have some big dataframes (ie 15000 obs. of 100 variables) in which one similarity is that one of the columns is named .id.

I need to prepare the big dataframes for merging with each other. In order to perform the merging, then the columns named .id needs to have the same values.

All the dataframes columns named .id have the same beginning of random values call it randomValues, but there is two different type of endings call them randomValues-ending_1 and randomValues-ending_2.

**The question**

How does one remove remove the -ending_1 and -ending_2 text from the .id column of these big dataframe?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Something like `gsub("-ending_\\d+$", "", vectorName)` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colnames(big.dataframe) <- gsub("-ending_\d+$","",colnames(big.dataframe))